# How can i store api response in variable and pass it to react popup video player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, react-popper

Call API using `fetch` and printed it on the console.

`app.js`

```
const onGridReady = (params) => {
    console.log("grid is ready");
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/get_all")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.results);
        params.api.applyTransaction({ add: resp.results });
      });
  };
```

using fetch to call api and printed it on console.

api response :

```
Array(80)
0:
Camera_Number: "Camera_1"
Company_Name: "Fraction Analytics Limited"
Floor Number: "Ground_Floor"
Group_Name: "Group_1"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/0"
[[Prototype]]: Object

1:
Camera_Number: "Camera_2"
Company_Name: "Fraction Analytics Limited"
Floor Number: "Ground_Floor"
Group_Name: "Group_1"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/1"
```

This response i got from API. now how to store API response in a react js variable. After storing data how pass `Video_Name:"http://localhost:4000/video/*"`  to react player source

Assign this response to react table :

```
 const columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Name", field: "Company_Name", filter: "agSetColumnFilter" },
    { headerName: "Floor", field: "Floor Number" },
    { headerName: "Group", field: "Group_Name" },
    { headerName: "Camera", field: "Camera_Number" },
    { headerName: "Videos", field: "Video_Name" },
    {
      headerName: "Actions",
      field: "Video_Name",
      cellRendererFramework: (params) => (
        <div>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            size="medium"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => actionButton(params)}
          >
            Play
          </Button>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];



<DialogContent>
  <iframe
    width="420"
    height="315"
    title="videos"
    src={("http://localhost:4000/video/0", "http://localhost:4000/video/1")}
  />
</DialogContent>;
```

For more code reference

> [CLICK HERE](https://github.com/iamharry-dev/modal_popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the click handler of the button. You cannot get row data with that.

Add a `colId` to column definition for actions. Then handle the `onCellClicked` action of the grid. You can get the row data using `params.node.data`.

```
const [videoName, setVideoName] = useState("");

function onCellClicked(params) {
    // maps to colId: "action" in columnDefs,
    if (params.column.colId === "action") {
      // set videoName for the row
      setVideoName(params.node.data.Video_Name);
      setOpen(true);
    }
}

// grid config
<AgGridReact
  ...
  rowData={response}
  onCellClicked={onCellClicked}>
</AgGridReact>

// access videoName in dialog content
<DialogContent>
 {/* <iframe width="420" height="315" title="videos" src={id} /> */}
 <div>{videoName}</div>
</DialogContent>
```

[Codesand box Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-zhukovsky-gt4mln?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 2):

you should be using the useState hook to store the response from the API

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

const onGridReady = (params) => {
    console.log("grid is ready");
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/get_all")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        setResponse(resp.results);
        params.api.applyTransaction({ add: resp.results });
      });
  };
```

then finally using the array in the iframe, and outputting an iframe for each link.

```
<DialogContent>
  {response.map(({Video_Name})=> 
  <iframe
    width="420"
    height="315"
    title="videos"
    src={Video_Name}
    />
  )}
</DialogContent>;
```

Comment: @HariprasathLakshmanan Sorry, small mistake. Set the initial value of response to an empty array. const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
Try this and then let me know.

Comment: Its working but at a time multiple popup player open and playing same video. refer here  `https://github.com/iamharry-dev/modal_popup/blob/main/error_1.png`

Comment: We are getting the video links from the API. Can you log the urls?
console.log(response.map(({Video_Name}) => Video_Name)); 
and confirm if the links are different.

Also, according to the code, the list of all the videos will be outputted.
Are you trying to display a single video at a time?

Comment: Yes actually i give button to all the response and populated it to react table [link](https://github.com/iamharry-dev/modal_popup/blob/main/1.png) like this when i click play button i want play single video at a time

Comment: is there any update on above issue ???